# Copy complete css path into string

Tags: css, string, path, copy

I'm trying to get the css tree string of an element deeply in a document. With Firebug and Chrome I can easily get the selector but I need the full path.

The reason is that I need to modify a WordPress theme based on the class of the body on some pages. I know this is probably not best practice, but if one of you knows a method to copy the whole string I would be very happy.

Example:
body.page-id-362 > div#page.boxed > div#main.sidebar-none > div.wf-wrap > div.wf-container-main > div#content.content > div > div.vc_col-sm-3.wpb_column.column_container

The one I'm trying to copy is even deeper and writing them by hand takes pretty long.

Comment: Do you really need to specify every element from the body to the target element? An id should be unique in the page, so your example should work fine as `body.page-id-362 #content > div > div.vc_col-sm-3.wpb_column.column_container`. Depending on what the HTML looks like you would likely be able to remove most of the selectors between the closest id and the element.

Answer (score 0):

### Chrome *(winner)*

- Right click on the desired element and click <kbd>inspect Element</kbd>
- Once the console pops you'll see the tag highlighted,
  Right click and select: <kbd>Copy CSS path</kbd>

[image]

The result for the last paragraph of your Question ended like:

```
#question > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.postcell > div > div.post-text > p:nth-child(4)
```

---

### Firefox

Right click the desired element, click <kbd>Inspect element</kbd>. You should see than something like:

[image]

Than **Right click** the last (desired) Tag Element and click <kbd>Copy Unique Selector</kbd>.
Doing this for the last Paragraph in your question it gave me:

```
.postcell > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(4)
```

---

### Firebug

<kbd>F12</kbd> it's quite easy, inspect [image] the desired element and:

- **Right click** the first Tag after the [Edit] button [image]
- <kbd>Copy CSS Path</kbd>

[image]

I.E: I did this with your last Question's Paragraph and got this:

**CSS Path:**

```
html body.question-page.new-topbar div.container div#content div div#mainbar div#question.question table tbody tr td.postcell div div.post-text p
```

**XPath**

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[1]/p[4]
```